# delete previous data before inserting new ones in each button click

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have a form that contains a DataGridView, a button "selection", and a ComboBox. How can I delete the previous data inserted into the dataGridView each time I click the button "selection"?

This is my code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    compteDataGridView.Update();
    compteDataGridView.Refresh(); 
    try
    {
        String c = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) == true) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) == true) && (comboBox1.SelectedItem == c) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text) == true))
        {
              SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
              connection.Open();

              req = "select numero_cpte,intitulé_cpte from compte where type_cpte='"+c+"';"; 
              SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(req, connection);
              dr = new SqlDataAdapter(req, connection);
              dr.Fill(ds, "compte");
              compteDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["compte"];
              connection.Close();
```

NB:the selection is based in the item selected by User (comboBox1)

Comment: FYI: You don't need these `== true` in your if statements.  `if`s check for a boolean expression, which `.IsNullOrEmpty` returns.

Comment: ok thanks CAbbott and Nathan A for the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This before your Update call should do the trick:

```
compteDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

An alternative method would be:

```
compteDataGridView.DataSource = null;
```

Comment: thanks Haris but I have an error it said that "I can't delete the list" :/ I place this code at the end of my method

Comment: The code is supposed to go before compteDataGridView.Update();. It might be that you need another refresh call afterwards, can't test it on my machine right now.